# Unable to show a newly created PHP page from Yii2 (on XAMPPV3.2.2)

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am a newbie.

1. Installed XAMPP 3.2.2 on Windows 10.
2. Installed Yii 2.0.13 (advanced template) in XAMPP.
3. Started the Apache Server.
4. Yii2 Development Environment Initiated. Were able to open the page from browser and all the links are working at this point in time.
5. Navigated to the FrontEnd->Site->Layout and copied about.php to
   testabout.php
6. In the "FrontEnd"->"Views"->"Layout"->Main.PHP, added a new Menubar Item as shown in the blocked letters (Italic Items are what was already in there).

   *$menuItems = [
       ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
       ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
       ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],*
       **['label' => 'Custom Link', 'url' => ['/site/testabout']],**
   *];*
7. A new link called "Custom Link" is added to the Landing Page with no issues.
   When I click on the link, it shows the below error message

*Not Found (#404)
Page not found.
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.*

**Need your inputs to fix this issue.**

For sure, i searched for a similar issue in this forum and either I found them not related to the steps I performed or I cannot understand their answers.

Some Updates I have done are as follows:
1) Created a .htaccess file in the frontend->Web Folder and Backend->Web Folder;

Comment: Include your source code so that we can help

Comment: testabout.php is the file i newly added. Code of the file is <? php
echo "this is the about page"
?>

Comment: You need to create a new action in site controller then only it works. Your adding [/site/testabout] in this "site" is controller name and "testabout" is action name.just adding view file is not enough. you read basic flow of yii2 MVC here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html

Comment: Thank you Vishva. I'll read the strucutre.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an action in site controller
1.create an action in

> frontend->controllers->siteController    action name = 'testabout'

example,

```
public function actionTestabout()
{
  $return_value = 'Haii';
  return $return_value;  //this will print 'Haii' on screen..
}
```

but, you need to render a view file..(the proper way)
example,
 make a new file named '

> test_about.php

' and put it in

> frontend->views->site

.

then add a something in

> test_about.php

ex:  `echo 'haii';`

then, modify your action like this,

```
public function actionTestabout()
{
  return $this->render('test_about); //shows 'haii'
}
```

I hope this will help you